# Finding the second-largest value in an array

Tags: python, algorithm

The problem is stated as:

> You are given as input an unsorted array of n distinct numbers, where
>   n is a power of 2. Give an algorithm that identifies the
>   second-largest number in the array and that uses at most n+log(n)−2
>   comparisons.

I've seen many references to the problem online but most focus on a recursive approach. I wonder why that is. Below is how I approached it. Is there an issue with this implementation? Why choose recurrence here?

```
testCase = [10, 9, 5, 4, 11, 100, 120, 110]
def getSecondHighest(a):
  hi = mid = lo = 0
  for i in range(0, len(a)):
    x = a[i]
    if ( x > hi):
      lo = mid
      mid = hi
      hi = x
    elif ( x < hi and x > mid):
      lo = mid
      mid = x
    elif ( x < lo):
      lo = x
  return mid

print(getSecondHighest(testCase))
```

Comment: your test case only has 8 numbers. should it not have either 4,9 or 16?

Comment: Your code is broken since it uses too many comparisons. In your code, count the actual comparisons and `assert` that there aren't too many. Use more than one test case. Especially rising numbers and falling numbers make interesting test cases.

Comment: @RolandIllig I used a bunch of test cases and couldn't find a failing one.  What do you mean by "too many comparisons"

Comment: @RolandIllig Code is "broken" when it doesn't work as intended. Code that's ugly/inefficient/doesn't follow coding conventions may still work as intended and as such not "broken".

Comment: @ChatterOne I'd love to know what makes the code ugly/inefficient. Could you clarify?

Comment: @silkAdmin It was just an example. I don't think the code is inefficient. I do think it's ugly though :-P Variable names are meaningless and the function name uses camel case instead of snake case, for example. You can look at PEP8 to get an idea.

Comment: @ChatterOne Will do, thanks. I have about 3 hours experience of Python under my belt so I didn't even know snake case was favored :).

Comment: Guys many of your comments would be fine answers. Just post them as such!

Comment: @silkAdmin The specification clearly says: _Use at most \$n+\log(n)-2\$ comparisons._ Therefore your code does not conform to that specification. For the sequence `[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]` your code uses 36 comparisons instead of the allowed 12.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Trust the math. When the `x > hi` comparison fails, there is no need to test against `x < hi`. The streamlined code should look like

  ```
      if x > hi:
          ....
      elif x > mid:
          ....
      else
          ....
  ```
- Follow the math. In the worst case - the array sorted in the descending order - (almost) every element has go through two comparisons, making total of \$2n - 2\$, which is larger than the goal of \$n + \log{n} - 2\$
- A correct approach is to arrange an elimination tournament (\$n - 1\$ comparisons to determine a champion), while keeping track of those who lose only to the champion. This makes \$log{n}\$ candidates for the second place, and \$\log{n} - 1\$ comparisons to determine the second. For the details, watch Alex Stepanov lectures starting with [lecture 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RdQM3c-0eiA), or just see the [final code](https://github.com/rjernst/stepanov-components-course/blob/master/code/lecture11/min_element1_2.h).

  I highly recommend to watch the entire course, even if you are not interested in C++.

Comment: Well, you could kind of "cheat" a bit and use a count sort to get \$O(n-2)\$ comparisons (Because you still need to find the two integers that you need) :-P But of course you'd need some constraint on the max value.

Comment: @ChatterOne Using a count sort would be useless, "unsorted array of n distinct numbers".

Comment: @Peilonrayz Huh? Yes, the fact that they are unsorted is exactly why a count sort would be useful.

Comment: @ChatterOne They're "distinct numbers", your count sort will produce the same list, but with each having a 'count' of 1.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Yes, but that doesn't matter. What matters is that the list will already be sorted and all you need to do is find the top two which are actually present, hence the \$O(n-2)\$ comparisons

Answer (score 2):

> I have about 3 hours experience of Python under my belt so I didn't even know snake case was favored :).

Fortunately Python follows the style guide [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), and so if you read that you'll be up-to-date on all, most, of Pythons conventions.

However it mostly comes down to using `snake_case`, removing some unneeded parentheses, and keeping to Python's somewhat strict whitespace rulings.

---

As for your code, you don't need `lo`, and since you have at most 4 / 5 comparisons per loop your code probably doesn't fit in the limit of \$n + \log(n) − 2\$.
You should also use `for x in a`, rather than getting `i` to then index `a`.
And so after a little cleanup you can get:

```
def get_second_highest(a):
    hi = mid = 0
    for x in a:
        if x > hi:
            mid = hi
            hi = x
        elif x < hi and x > mid:
            lo = mid
            mid = x
    return mid

print(get_second_highest([10, 9, 5, 4, 11, 100, 120, 110]))
```

---

This really depends on what you count as a comparison. For example does `for i in range(10)` count as zero, one or ten comparisons.
If you were to write the same thing in any other language it'd definitely be ten, `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)`.
And so if you count using loops as 0, then it's really quite simple. You can do it in less than n comparisons.

To do this go through half the array, and move the higher ones to the front of the array. Keep doing this for the bit length of the size of the list.

```
def get_second_heighest(a):
    mid = len(a)
    for _ in range(mid.bit_length()):
        mid, add = divmod(mid, 2)
        add += mid
        for i in range(mid):
            if a[i] < a[i + add]:
                a[i], a[i + add] = a[i + add], a[i]
    if len(a) >= 2:
        return a[1]
    return None
```

Comment: Thanks @Peilonrayz ! However, I am really confused by the second part of your answer. Why using `bit_length` length? I don't see how it correlates to the actual length of the array. `mid, add = divmod(mid, 2)` what is this for ?

Comment: @silkAdmin Think of the numbers in binary form. Take `bin(10)` which is 0b1010, so the bit length of that is 4. Then look at `divmod`, where we reassign `mid` as `mid //= 2`. So taking 10 again, since we loop 4 times, we have the following numbers: `(bin(10), bin(10 // 2), bin(10 // 2 // 2), bin(10 // 2 // 2 // 2))`, which are, 1010, 101, 10, 1. And so we're halving the number until it reaches zero. However rather than using `while mid`, instead of the current for loop, I instead used some binary logic to reduce the amount of comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Peilonrayz, It's a pretty impressive thinking there. I need to take the time to understand this.